# Django Dockerized with Celery and Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, django-celery

I'm struggling to create a docker image for my Django project. I'm using Celery with Redis as a broker and Postgres.
When creating container got this error:
`django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: No address associated with hostname`

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV DJANGO_ENV dev
ENV DOCKER_CONTAINER 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /code/requirements.txt

COPY /src/ /code/
WORKDIR /code/

EXPOSE 8000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    expose:
      - "5432"

  redis:
    image: "redis:alpine"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bash -c "python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput && python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  celery:
    build: .
    command: celery -A core worker -l info
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  celery-beat:
    build: .
    command: celery -A core beat -l info
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? I'm quite sure its something with the database config in settings.py as it was working fine before I changed that and I was able to run my app and test celery.

Comment: I think issue can be that Postgres didn't started up. Depends on unfortunately don't wait till postgres will properly setup. Could you try add `sleep 20` in you `web` service command?

Comment: Check the resulting name of the containers with `docker ps` it should contain the folder name as well. Use that as the hostname.

Comment: I have found problem somewhere else. Turned out I had some container using db service with older postgress and it was using old data. There was error on top of the logs but they were to long to notice in terminal. Had to run `docker-compose down` to clear the db and everything worked as expected with the next build